# Change Particle System random between two constants value (Start speed)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Tl;DR:** How to change a particle system *Random between two constants* and *Constant* values using a C# script ?

Hello,

I have a **particle system** prefab with a script, i want the script to change many of the particle system stats when it gets instantiated (*Awake*)

I have the following code (i removed some elements we don't need):

```
    // Particle fields
    ParticleSystem particle;
    ParticleSystem.MinMaxCurve startSpeed;
    ParticleSystem.MinMaxCurve startSize;
    ParticleSystem.MinMaxCurve rateOverTime;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Initialization();

        startSpeed.constantMin *= 1.2f;
        startSpeed.constantMax *= 1.2f;
        startSpeed.mode = ParticleSystemCurveMode.TwoConstants;

        startSize.constant *= 1.2f;
        startSize.mode = ParticleSystemCurveMode.Constant;

        rateOverTime.constant *= 1.2f;
        rateOverTime.mode = ParticleSystemCurveMode.Constant;
    }

    private void Initialization()
    {
        particle = /*Get the particle system component*/;

        startSpeed = particle.main.startSpeed;
        startSize = particle.main.startSize;
        rateOverTime = particle.emission.rateOverTime;
    }
```

After testing, the *Awake* function is correctly called when a particle is instantiated but *start speed*, *start size*, and *rate over time* remain the same on the instanciated object as on the prefab.

I tried:

- Setting the value to a specific float with **=** (it should work according to documentation)
- Changin the mode with `startSpeed.mode = ParticleSystemCurveMode.TwoConstants;`
- Creating fields curveMin and curveMax, to which i allocate the `constantMin` and `constantMax`, and editing them directly with `curveMin = 200;`
- Applying back the changes with `particle.main.startSpeed = startSpeed` but it returns an error `Cannot modify the return value of 'ParticleSystem.main' because it is not a variable`

None of it worked...

Can anybody help me with this please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed,

I made two error that made my code not work.

The first was stupid, i was getting the wrong particle system module component, instead of getting the particle's particle system with `GetComponent<ParticleSystem>()`,
i was getting the prefab's particle system...

The second was that i wasn't reapplying back the changes to the particle system, which was solved thanks to @DerHugo answer.

Big thanks to everyone who helped me solving this !

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is that you only modify your locally stored `struct` values but those are not applied back to the particle system.

```
var mainModule = partcle.main;
var emissionModule = particle.emission;

var startSpeed = mainModule.startSpeed;
var startSize = mainModule.startSize;
var rateOverTime = emissionModule .rateOverTime;

startSpeed.constantMax *= 1.2f;
startSpeed.mode = ParticleSystemCurveMode.TwoConstants;

startSize.constant *= 1.2f;
startSize.mode = ParticleSystemCurveMode.Constant;

rateOverTime.constant *= 1.2f;
rateOverTime.mode = ParticleSystemCurveMode.Constant;

// => Apply back those changes!
mainModule.startSpeed = startSpeed;
mainModule.startSize = startSize;
emissionModule.rateOverTime = rateOverTime;
```

The modules property values though are also `struct` types meaning whatever they return is just a copy and completely decoupled from the underlying system! => You have to apply them back to the according module(s).

The `ParticleSystem` modules themselves are a very weird (imho inconsistent) exception. Usually you would use `class` references to indicate that any modification on properties of the instance are "linked" and e.g. applied to the particle system. In this case though they basically only consist of properties hooked into native c++ callbacks so it doesn't really matter if the modules are class or struct types.

Comment: It gives me an error: Cannot modify the return value of 'ParticleSystem.main' because it is not a variable, so the code can't compile

Comment: @draymone was typing this on my phone ^^ should be fixed now